# Read Script Tags from appSettings.config in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, appsettings

I want to read a script tag as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  window.something || function (e, t) {....</script>
```

from  app settings file as

```
<add key="SomeScripts" value="<script type="text/javascript">  window.something || function (e, t) {....</script>"/>
```

However I get error and I cant add script tags.Is there any other best way of doing this?

Thanks,
Suhas

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good pratice to do this. You could just have a bool value in the appSettings and check if it is true to generate the script on the page. For sample:

```
<add key="SomeScripts" value="true" />
```

And in the webpage (I am not sure if it is mvc or webforms).

```
if (bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeScripts"])) 
{
    // generate the script here...
}
```

If you have it in multiple places, and, it is a MVC application, you could make a `PartialView` and just put it in the `Shared` to call from everywhere. In webforms, create a `web user control` (`.ascx` file) and call from everywhere.

Comment: :Problem is  I have to do it in multiple pages so I  wanted to read the script from one single place.Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: If it is a MVC application, you could make a `PartialView` and just put it in the `Shared` to call from everywhere. In webforms, create a web user control (`.ascx` file) and call from everywhere.

Comment: Thank you.But in this approach whenever there is a script change required code need to be compiled but when we add it into settings files.This can be avoided.What do you feel?